# __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given when run

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

- 

Hi

I have this code python code, trying to make one parent class Publication, and 2 child classes (book and magazine).

then it tries to create an object and added it to a list based on the user choice from the list

```
class Publication:
    title=""
    price=0.0

    def __init__(self,title,price):
        self.title=title
        self.price=price

    def display(self):
        print("title: "+self.title)
        print("\nprice: "+str(self.price))



class Book(Publication):
    author=""

    def __init__(self,title,price,author):
        super().__init__(self,title,price)
        self.author=author

    def display(self):
        print("title: "+self.title)
        print(", price: "+ str(self.price))
        print(", author: "+self.author)


class Magazine(Publication):
    issue = ""

    def __init__(self, title, price, issue):
        super().__init__(self, title, price)
        self.issue = issue

    def display(self):
        print("title: " + self.title)
        print(", price: " + str(self.price))
        print(", issue: " + self.issue)



# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    choice=1;
    bookList=[]
    MagazineList=[]

    while(choice!=0):
        print("Publication System")
        print("Select a service:")
        print("1) Add Book")
        print("2) Add Magazine")
        print("3) Display Book Lists")
        print("4) Display Magazine Lists")
        print("5) Exit")
        choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))

        if choice == 1:
            bookTitle=str(input("Enter the book title: "))
            bookAuthor = str(input("Enter the book author: "))
            bookPrice = float(input("Enter the book price: "))

            book=Book(bookTitle,bookPrice,bookAuthor)
            bookList.append(book)

        elif choice == 2:
            MagazineTitle=str(input("Enter the magazine title: "))
            MagazineIssue = str(input("Enter the magazine issue: "))
            MagazinePrice = float(input("Enter the magazine price: "))

            magazine=Magazine(MagazineTitle,MagazinePrice,MagazineIssue)
            MagazineList.append(magazine)

        elif choice == 3:
            for i in range(len(bookList)):
                print(bookList[i]+"\n")

        elif choice == 4:
            for i in range(len(MagazineList)):
                print(MagazineList[i]+"\n")

        elif choice == 5:
            print("Exiting!")
        else:
            print("Invalid choice!!")
```

when I run it,  it shows me this error:

```
Publication System
Select a service:
1) Add Book
2) Add Magazine
3) Display Book Lists
4) Display Magazine Lists
5) Exit
Enter choice: 1
Enter the book title: python fundamentals
Enter the book author: eric
Enter the book price: 40
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 10/Advanced Programming Language/Lab/Q1OtherGroups/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    book=Book(bookTitle,bookPrice,bookAuthor)
  File "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 10/Advanced Programming Language/Lab/Q1OtherGroups/main.py", line 19, in __init__
    super().__init__(self,title,price)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

how may I resolve it? I have seen similar problems but did not find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `self` explicitly while calling the class methods.

It should be

```
super().__init__(title, price)
```

instead of

```
super().__init__(self, title, price)
```

Answer (score 1):

`super().__init__` is a bound method, already including `self`. You don't need to pass `self` explicitly. For example,

```
class Book(Publication):    
    def __init__(self, title, price, author):
        super().__init__(title, price)
        self.author = author

    # etc
```